# Enterprise Library Logging tracelistener extension issue with resolving ILogFormatter

Tags: enterprise-library, containers, trace-listener

I have been sitting with a problem for quite a while now and I just can't seem to find what I'm missing.
I have written a custom trace listener component for Enterprise Library 5.0 for the Logging application block which works but the configured ILogFormatter just won't resolve and so I always end up with the basic string text when it gets handled by my component.
I saw in the enterprise library source code that they use the "Container.ResolvedIfNotNull()" method. It doesn't seem to work for me. I need it to write out a custom formatted string for my component to use. You know, not just the message but the timestamp, machinename, threadId, etc.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I wrote this in my own new assembly. This is not a change made in the Entlib source code.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the code? In particular the method that returns your type registrations?

Comment: I do not recall having something like that. Would you care to explain?

Comment: I also started this discussion on CodePlex:http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/261749

Comment: Its been resolved. Check the link above.

Comment: @dandrejvv: Can you post the answer here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I've mentioned on this site: http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/261749

When you create your `CreationExpression` in the `TraceListener` data class make sure you have a flat constructor definition. To put it in other words, don't return:

```
() => new MyTraceListener(new TraceListenerConfig(..., Container.ResolvedIfNotNull<ILogFormatter>(), ...));
```

just have it in the constructor of the `MyTraceListener`:

```
() => new MyTraceListener(..., Container.ResolvedIfNotNull<ILogFormatter>(), ...);
```